# CSS applied to bootstrap Jumbotron works inline, but not externally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to apply a background to a jumbotron. It works fine if I use inline styling but not when using an external stylesheet. I have linked the external stylesheet correctly and i can change other attributes of the jumbotron in it but not the background image. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

html with inline styling:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/homepage.css">

        </head>
    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=
             "background-image:url('Images/background.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%">
            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3">Welcome.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Text</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="m-t-2">       
        </div>

        <div id="cardDiv">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

css: (height works, background image doesnt)

```
.jumbotron {

    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('Images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible fix might be that your file directory isn't configured properly.

As good practice, follow this:

```
root
|
index.html
<other html files>
CSS Folder/
    |
     <CSS files>
Images Folder/
    |
     <image files>
```

As for the solution:
try this:

```
.jumbotron {
height: 400px;
background-image: url('../Images/background.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your folder structure looks something like the following:

```
- index.html
- CSS/
    -- homepage.css
    -- bootstrap.min.css
- Images/
    -- background.jpg
```

The path to the `Images/` folder from your HTML file will be different than from within the `homepage.css` file. You need to use relative paths to get to the `Images` folder, which should be one level higher. You can use `..` to go up one level in the folder structure within the CSS `url()` property.

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('../Images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works thatnks. Just moved the image to different directory